# Android Upload Images(Okhttp3) without interface

Tags: java, php, android, okhttp

I am a student, just learn Android develop few days,
There have a question about how can upload a image in background without user interface.

I'm mean there already have the file path ,I don't need the user click to select images,When user run the activity,the image with auto upload. I know i can using okhttp3 ,such as below video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K48jnbM8yS4
(I'm think this is good video ,is my stupid not know how can modify the code   )

However, in the video , the MainActivity such as this

```
package app.file_upload;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.nbsp.materialfilepicker.MaterialFilePicker;
import com.nbsp.materialfilepicker.ui.FilePickerActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
                return;
            }
        }

        enable_button();
    }

    private void enable_button() {

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new MaterialFilePicker()
                            .withActivity(UploadActivity.this)
                            .withRequestCode(10)
                            .start();

                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 100 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            enable_button();
        }else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
            }
        }
    }

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            progress = new ProgressDialog(UploadActivity.this);
            progress.setTitle("Uploading");
            progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progress.show();

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File f  = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH));
                    String content_type  = getMimeType(f.getPath());

                    String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);

                    RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("type",content_type)
                            .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
                            .build();

                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("URL_TO_THE_SERVER/YOUR_SCRIPT.php")
                            .post(request_body)
                            .build();

                    try {
                        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                        if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                            throw new IOException("Error : "+response);
                        }

                        progress.dismiss();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });

            t.start();




        }
    }

    private String getMimeType(String path) {

        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);

        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
}
```

for my case , I only upload the image ,but **i not need the user interface** (Such as button to select picture),So I'm try to modify the code ,such as below :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File f = new File(" /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/abc.package.name/files/images.jpg");
        String content_type  = getMimeType(f.getPath());
        String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);

        RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("type",content_type)
                .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("My php File Link ")
                .post(request_body)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                throw new IOException("Error : "+response);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }












    private String getMimeType(String path) {

        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);

        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
}
```

I'm only need to use okhttp3 to upload image in backround task , no need any interface ,But I'm feel difficult for me ,maybe i am new user of android studio...>_<

Can anyone help me to modify the code ....

My php code also here:

```
<?php 

    $file_path = "images/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    }else {
        echo "error";
    }


 ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? What result do you get? There are two possible issues I see straight away. 1. [Network activity on the main thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). 2. [Possible permission issue opening the file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Comment: The first code is correct . The problem is I don't know how to modify the code. I need to cut the select button and using default path when user opening the app. The first code is from the video, 100% correct ,than I try to modify to second one(NO select button and already set up default upload path)....., After using the second code, no any response ，really sad :(